# Playing mp3 file with winmm.dll in C# works well in GUI app, but does not work in cosnsole app

Tags: c#, winapi, mp3

So, I am trying to play mp3 file in C# console application.

```
class Program
{
    [DllImport("winmm.dll")]
    static extern Int32 mciSendString(string command,
        StringBuilder buffer, int bufferSize, IntPtr hwndCallback);
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string filePath = "1.mp3";
        string command = "open \"" + filePath + "\" type mpegvideo alias MyTag";
        Int32 err = mciSendString(command, null, 0, IntPtr.Zero);
        command = "play MyTag";
        err = mciSendString(command, null, 0, IntPtr.Zero);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

But I'm getting error 266 (`MCIERR_CANNOT_LOAD_DRIVER`) when try to open file. Intersting thing is that the same code works well if I put it into button callback of GUI app (Windows Forms Application). Also it works if I change code ommitting file open.

```
string filePath = "1.mp3";
string command = "play " + filePath;
Int32 err = mciSendString(command, null, 0, IntPtr.Zero);
```

It also works well but I'd like to separate open action.

I'm using Microsoft Visual Studio 2008, .NET 3.5 (tested also on .NET 2.0 with the same results), Windows 7 32-bit.

Any ideas why is it so?

Comment: Video players usually require [STAThread] on the Main() method.  Or omit "type mpegvideo" to let MCI figure out what decoder is appropriate for an .mp3 file.

Comment: Yes, variant with [STAThread] on the Main() method works well. Thanks.